# sql query doesn't give me all the months

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a "customers" table with many columns. I need to use only two of them. date(the date that the customer was registerd), referrer( how did the customer find us: google or facebook or friends). I need for each month to show how many customers added by each referrer. for example: 2016-8 4 customers by facebook, 10 customers by friends and 13 customers by google). of course it should give me for each month the result in the example.

I tried this query - but it doesn't give me all the months only 2 of the months and one of them is being shown twice. can someone please review my query?

```
SELECT  referrer,date, COUNT(`date`)  
FROM `customers`        
GROUP BY `referrer`;
```

Comment: Try group by referrer, date :)

Comment: it is group by referrer in the query I posted no?\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT referrer,date, COUNT(date)
FROM customers
GROUP BY Year(date), MONTH(date), referrer;
```

If you want to select the output for a certain year you can try this:

```
SELECT referrer,date, COUNT(date)
FROM customers
WHERE record_date.YEAR = 2016
GROUP BY Year(date), MONTH(date), referrer;
```

Comment: thanks! maybe because I have days in my date it doesn't showing each month once? it showing me each month many times

Comment: If a month does not appear in the output then it might be due to the are no customers registered in that month.

Comment: you didn't understand me....I need for each month to show 3 ouputs: how many from facebook how many from friends and how many from google. it doesn't show month that isn't got customers and its great.